# My second monitor is not being detected

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop, and I'm trying to use my second monitor through HDMI from my NVIDIA 1050 Ti card but it is not being recognized. Before reinstalling Ubuntu, it worked.

Comment: Hi, welcome to askUbuntu! have you installed drivers for your card? try installing from ppa as outlined here: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaBesneatte, thats what I did and it is working perfectly now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I have managed to fix this problem was by updating my video card driver to the latest as mentioned [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux).

Start by uninstalling your old NVIDIA driver,

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
```

and then follow these steps:

**1. Add the PPA**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

**2. Install Video Drivers For Your Card**

Now as posted in this answer, you need to install the recommended driver for your card.

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

This will output something similar to this:

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==

vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000DDAsv000017AAsd000021D1bc03sc00i00
model    : GF106GLM [Quadro 2000M]
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
driver   : nvidia-304-updates - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-304 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-331 - distro non-free **recommended**
driver   : nvidia-331-updates - distro non-free
```

Then just install the driver labeled "recommended", so in this example it would be:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331
```

Once this is done reboot and you should be good to go.

Comment: I am surprised this doesn't have an ask ubuntu answer... perhaps you can update your answer to include the info from linuxconfig.org.... link only answers are not great because the link could die or change.

Comment: I went ahead and edited the answer to show you what it should look like :)

Answer (score 0):

I literally fought this issue for 3 years.
In my case, it got to the point that I would update by NVidia drivers, the second display would work - then every time I rebooted, the second display stopped working.

That said, try
xrandr -s 0
to enable your second monitor. xrandr -s 1 disables it.

Enter the command then plug the HDMI in. Cannot believe it but it seems to work.
Found the answer buried on this reddit page (https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/jd05v/enable_disable_external_monitor_from_command_line/)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was not fixed in Ubuntu, but in the BIOS settings. `nvidia-smi` worked, but it wouldn't detect the external monitor. On my Razer laptop, I solved the issue this way:

Open BIOS setting in Razer (by pressing F1 repeatedly while it boots)-> Chipset -> GPU Mode (change from "NVIDIA(R) Dynamic Display Switch" to "Discrete GPU only") -> Save&Exit -> Save Changes and Reset
-> Reboot

Hopefully there is an equivalent in non-Razer laptops.