# Ubuntu not showing second monitor connected

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

Recently built a computer that will be used for data processing. Here are the components:

- Motherboard: Tuf Gaming Z690-plus Wifi D4
- CPU: 12th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-12700K × 20
- No GPU
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
- GNOME version 3.36.8

I have two monitors that are connected and are mirroring each-other. I'd like to change the setting to have one monitor extend the other, but the system doesn't seem to be picking up on one of the monitors.

This is what the settings pane looks like:
[image]

This is the result of running `xrandr`:

```
$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

Again, I know that both monitors work since they are both showing the same screen. One is connected via HDMI and the other DP.

EDIT:

Here are the contents of `gpu-manager.log`

```
log_file: /var/log/gpu-manager.log
last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-was-loaded file
can't access /opt/amdgpu-pro/bin/amdgpu-pro-px
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.13.0-37-generic/kernel
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.13.0-37-generic/updates/dkms
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/5.13.0-37-generic/kernel
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/5.13.0-37-generic/updates/dkms
Is nvidia loaded? no
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? no
Is intel loaded? yes
Is radeon loaded? no
Is radeon blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu loaded? no
Is amdgpu blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu versioned? no
Is amdgpu pro stack? no
Is nouveau loaded? no
Is nouveau blacklisted? no
Is nvidia kernel module available? no
Is amdgpu kernel module available? no
Vendor/Device Id: 8086:4680
BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
Is boot vga? yes
Error: can't access /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.0/driver
The device is not bound to any driver.
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Does it require offloading? no
last cards number = 1
Has amd? no
Has intel? yes
Has nvidia? no
How many cards? 1
Has the system changed? No
Single card detected
```

Comment: How did you configure the mirroring? Or has the system done this by default since the start 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My second monitor is not being detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1157551/my-second-monitor-is-not-being-detected)

Comment: @matigo it was the default from the start. As you can see in the screenshot, there is no option listed to change it

Comment: Hmm ... this is interesting. From [the motherboard manual (PDF)](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1700/TUF_GAMING_Z690-PLUS_WIFI_D4/E19393_TUF_GAMING_Z690-PLUS_WIFI_D4_UM_V3_WEB.pdf), this is controlled by the CPU. [Based on your CPU](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/134594/intel-core-i712700k-processor-25m-cache-up-to-5-00-ghz.html), it should be possible to drive up to 4 displays. Have you confirmed that all of the system drivers are installed?

Comment: No, how would I do this?

Comment: @kanehekili That question/answer is specific to nvidia. Could you answer my question in a way that would work for my motherboard?

Comment: Sorry, that link couldn't help. Could you have look at a file named `gpu-manager.log` and paste its contents into your question?

Comment: @kanehekili I just updated my question.

Comment: @kanehekili I just added a bounty to this question.

Comment: @matigo I just added a bounty to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

linux-hardware.org [checked your board](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=04bcdd10e9) and it looks like that a driver is missing. That driver should be included in the kernel 5.13 or newer. You might compare your hardware using the `lspci -vv` command.

Since Ubuntu has a 5.4 or 5.8 kernel (check yours with `uname -a`) I would recommend the following test:
[Download](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/jammy-desktop-amd64.iso) Ubuntu 22.04 (the daily is pretty stable) and create a live USB Stick. Boot into it, then test your monitors. If it works, you might install that iso, since it is due to be released this month.

Comment: That worked, thanks. I'll award the bounty as soon as it lets me.